# Best way to approach optional parameters/default value in C++

Tags: c++, default-value, optional-parameters

I'm wondering if there's a way to do something like the following, all with one function:

```
    template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func (T chgx = x, T chg y = y, T chgz = z)
{
     x = chgx;
     y = chgy;
     z = chgz;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is set the default value to the value I want to change, so that way if I leave off some arguments, those values *aren't* changed. The above code doesn't work and I think I understand why (The function doesn't actually have access to those values so it throws an error).

What I'm wondering is if there is way to do something like I described above, all with one function. Is my only option to overload the function with multiple definitions to handle different numbers of arguments?

Comment: Do you want the ability to leave out a value? Or are you fine with passing a placeholder for null?

Comment: Please post sample code that demonstrates how you are thinking of using the function.

Comment: @Pradhan That would be fine, if that's the only way this is workable. I'm just wondering if something like this is possible.

Comment: When you say "those values aren't changed", aren't changed from what? If you don't supply a parameter then there is nothing telling it what value to have unless you give it a default.

Comment: @R Sahu It's just a trivial templated class holding three values (A vector). It's just for educational purposes.

Comment: Create a class which has an implicit constructor that takes the value and sets a flag to true. The default constructor sets the flag to false. Put as `const Blah<T>& x = Blah<T>()`. Now read the flag in your function whether to change or not.

Comment: @Isthisathing Ok. Lets wait for answers here and see if there's something simpler. Also, take a look at [Boost.Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) which gives you keyword arguments, and [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) which lets you pass in "null".

Comment: To be perfectly honest it's probably a better design to have a different function for each of `x`, `y`, `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by having a set of overloaded functions.

```
// First overload. Needs all arguments.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func (T chgx, T chgy, T chgz)
{
     x = chgx;
     y = chgy;
     z = chgz;
}

// Second overload. Needs two arguments.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func (T chgx, T chgy)
{
     x = chgx;
     y = chgy;
}

// Third overload. Needs one argument.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func (T chgx)
{
     x = chgx;
}

// You can have a fourth overload that takes no arguments.
// However, it's totally useless.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func ()
{
   // Nothing needs to be changed.
}
```

Something with less duplicate code (Thanks are due to @BenVoigt for the suggestion):

```
// Second overload. Needs two arguments.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func (T chgx, T chgy)
{
   func(chgx, chgy, z);
}

// Third overload. Needs one argument.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func (T chgx)
{
   func(chgx, y);
}

// You can have a fourth overload that takes no arguments.
// However, it's totally useless.
template <typename T>
void _class_<T>::func ()
{
   func(x);
}
```

Comment: Would that be considered the cleanest way to do it, though?

Comment: Too much code duplication.  One can implement each in terms of the one with fewer arguments, or the one with fewer arguments in terms of the one with the most, passing the variable default for the omitted arguments.

Comment: @Isthisathing, that seems very clean to me. If I knew a cleaner way, I would add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `boost::optional` which is a small wrapper that defaults to empty if no argument is given to it:

```
using boost::optional;

template<typename T>
void _class_<T>::func( optional<T> cx = {}, 
     optional<T> cy = {}, optional<T> cz = {} )
{
    if ( cx ) x = *cx;
    if ( cy ) y = *cy;
    if ( cz ) z = *cz;
}
```

You don't get move or reference semantics doing this though (so I still prefer R Sahu's solution)

Answer (score 1):

One way (again, which won't support move or reference semantics) is to make the function take variable arguments via an initializer list:

```
template<typename T>
void _class_<T>::func( std::initializer_list<T> items )
{
    T const *ptr = items.begin();

    if ( ptr != items.end() ) x = *ptr++;
    if ( ptr != items.end() ) y = *ptr++;
    if ( ptr != items.end() ) z = *ptr++;
}
```

Usage:

```
obj.func({ 1, 2, 3 });
obj.func({ 1 });
obj.func({});
```